# Setting up an M/M/1 Queueing Model in R with No Waiting Area

Tags: r, queueing

I am trying to set up a queueing model in R using the `queueing` library. I am trying to model a scenario with no waiting area. In other words, if the service individual is busy, the person will not wait and will go elsewhere. I'm not sure how to code this up beyond what I already have, which does not account for people not willing to wait. How could I implement this in R?

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(queueing)

mod1 <- QueueingModel(NewInput.MM1(lambda = lambda, mu = mu))
summary(mod1)
```

Comment: this looks interesting! good luck!

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.